# Tracing ADO.Net usage?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Is it possible to trace ADO.Net usage by libraries used by my application without post compilation techniques?

I'm interested in both when all ADO.Net objects are private to the libraries and when there are ADO.Net objects that I can reach from outside.

The libraries are third party libraries that controls their own database connections. It's not my code.

Comment: Would something like [mini-profiler](http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler) help? With that, you tweak your connection-creation code, and it automatically tracks all the commands executed and readers iterated...

Comment: I would like to use mini-profiler, but I don't own the connections and I don't create them. Hence my question.

Comment: so: what *does* create the connections? How they are created can be key here.

Comment: The libraries I use. They just pick up the connectionstrings from .config.

Comment: which libraries? for example, if they use the DbProviderFactory API, it might be possible to inject into them by swapping the factory

Answer (score 0):

Off-the-wall suggestion but could you possibly proxy the connections to the database server at the TCP level, and count statistics that way?

i.e. implement a TCP server that listens on TCP port 1433 for connections from your application, with the connection string altered to point to your proxy instead of the server. When received, open a TCP connection to the original SQL Server, and transparently pass traffic between the application and the server. This gives you the opportunity to log statistics such as number of connections, data transferred, duration of connections etc.

Alternatively, would it be enough to just analyse the TCP traffic under test using something like Wireshark?

Comment: I have SQL Server profiler which already does all this, but I'm looking for a simpler way to get output to glimpse or mini-profiler.